# Angular - Crossfade between images

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a cross fade effect in Angular but the images keep pulsating instead of fading into each other. How can I fix it?

**animations.ts**

```
import { trigger, style, animate, transition, state } from '@angular/animations';

export const fade = [
  trigger('fade', [
    state('in', style({ 'opacity': '1' })),
    state('out', style({ 'opacity': '0' })),
    transition('* <=> *', [
      animate(500)
    ])
  ])
];

export enum AnimationState {
  IN = 'in',
  OUT = 'out'
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  heroImageArray = [
    "https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/277987267/q%3D80_m%3D2000/v2?webp=true&sig=082269b7b07ec17da1847d5c20cffee3a3a91af1f474eb3fd908eba828d5327c",
    "https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/253947845/q%3D80_h%3D450/v2?webp=true&sig=c645b242f19581b17df5bc68d54ee4e5a3c2f5b1ddd41791683ed9c03c455151"
  ];
  heroActiveImage: string =
    "https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/277987267/q%3D80_m%3D2000/v2?webp=true&sig=082269b7b07ec17da1847d5c20cffee3a3a91af1f474eb3fd908eba828d5327c";
  state = AnimationState.IN;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.toggleImg();
  }

  toggleImg() {
    let count = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      if (count === this.heroImageArray.length) {
        count = 0;
      }
      this.heroActiveImage = this.heroImageArray[count];
      count++;
    }, 3000);
  }

  onDone() {
    this.toggleState();
  }

  toggleState() {
    this.state =
      this.state === AnimationState.IN ? AnimationState.OUT : AnimationState.IN;
  }
}
```

**Stackblitz here:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anim-fade-img-gga34g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you has an array of pictures you can have an unique imagen and do

```
fade out--change the image--fade in--fade-out--change the image--fade in-...
```

or to have two images (one over the another) and make

```
fade out --interchange the images --fade out --iterchange the images...
```

I put the two animations

```
  animations: [
    trigger("fade", [
      transition("false=>true", [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate("2500ms", style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ])
    ]),
    trigger("fade2", [
      transition("false=>true", [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate("2500ms", style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ]),
      transition("true=>false", [animate("2500ms", style({ opacity: 0 }))])
    ])
  ]
```

(see that "fade" only make a fade out). If you has an array of images - I suggest that, if you make a stackblitz you can use [Lorem picsum](https://picsum.photos/) like instead your server or another one

```
  imageArray = [
    "https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1",
    "https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2",
     ....
  ];
```

You can has an html like

```html
    <img [@fade2]="toogle2"  
         (@fade2.done)="onFade2($event)"  
         [src]="imageArray[count2%imageArray.length]">
```

or, if you use two images

```html
    <div style="position:relative">
        <img [@fade]="toogle"  style="position:absolute;z-index:10"
         (@fade.done)="onFade($event)"
         [src]="imageArray[count%imageArray.length]">
        <img [src]="imageArray[(count+imageArray.length-1)%imageArray.length]">
    </div>
```

The functions onFade and onFade2 use rxjs operator 'timer' to mantain the images visibles during the time you choose

```
  onFade(event: any) {
    timer(2000).subscribe(() => {
      if (event.fromState)
        this.count = (this.count + 1) % this.imageArray.length;
      this.toogle = !this.toogle;
    });
  }
  onFade2(event: any) {
    if (!event.fromState) {
      timer(2000).subscribe(() => {
        this.toogle2 = !this.toogle2;
      });
    } else {
      this.toogle2 = !this.toogle2;
      if (event.fromState)
        this.count2 = (this.count2 + 1) % this.imageArray.length;
    }
  }
```

You can see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8us4dk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Updated** thanks to the Eliezer Vegas's comment, I could improve the code so "pause" the animation:

```
  animations: [
    trigger("fade", [
      transition("false=>true", [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate("2500ms 2000ms", style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ])
    ]),
    trigger("fade2", [
      transition("false=>true", [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate("2500ms", style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ]),
      transition("true=>false", [animate("2500ms 2000ms", style({ opacity: 0 }))])
    ])
  ]
```

And

```
  onFade(event: any) {
      if (event.fromState)
        this.count = (this.count + 1) % this.imageArray.length;
      this.toogle = !this.toogle;
  }
  onFade2(event: any) {
      this.toogle2 = !this.toogle2;
      if (event.fromState)
        this.count2 = (this.count2 + 1) % this.imageArray.length;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

There were some changes needed to be performed but basically I changed the value passed to `animate()` from 500 to 2000 (no worries, with the changes now you can just adjust the transition time you want by changing the value passed to the animate function), also I moved the block of code to change the image to the toggleState function and reorder the strings in the `heroImageArray` (that was to prevent the error you mentioned about the first image).

Here you have the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anim-fade-img-yupxe1?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Note: to slow or speed the transition, just change the value passed to the `animate` function.

Comment: Thanks for this, how do I adjust the time that the image stays on screen?

Comment: I understand you want a delay after the image goes in. In this case, you can pass a string to the animate function, like this `animate("2s 1s")` (being 2 secs of transition and 1 of delay). Also you need to change the transition function call because the delay will apply for `in => out` as for `out => in` making a blank space delay for 2 secs. You need to have 2 transition calls, the first `transition("in => out", animate("2s 2s"))` (this will set the time the image stays to 2 secs. I updated the code, you can check it for info) and a second `transition("out => in", animate("2s 0.5s"))`.

Comment: Thanks from this comment, @EliezerVerasVargas, I dind'nt know how pause the animations -I used a sledgehammers to crack nuts, well, really a rxjs timer- :)

Answer (score 1):

The image should be changed when the state is OUT, otherwise it's gonna flicker. I've forked and updated your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anim-fade-img-37nfw2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts), the changes are in animations (made the animation 1500ms instead of 500ms), and changed the first picture to the second picture from the array (so it won't flicker to the same picture.

edit: I think it would also be better the change the image on the toggleState event when `this.state === AnimationState.OUT` (so you know you are switching when the picture is faded out)

Comment: It still seems a bit buggy when the image goes into the first image. How can I fix this?

Comment: like I said, you should switch the image when fade out finishes, check out my updated stackblitz @methuselah

Comment: Thanks this works very well, is there any way to slow down the animation transition between the photos