# Angular fade in/out when text changes don't works

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation

I'm currently trying to build a word carousel in Angular. The idea is to have an array with x elements that are changing every 3 seconds with a fade so that it don't looks hard. The problem is that I've just managed to show the fade animation on the initial page load but not on every word change.

This is my animation:

```
animations : [
  trigger('fadeAnimation', [
    state('in', style({opacity: 1})),
    transition(':enter', [
      style({opacity: 0}),
      animate(600)
    ]),
    transition(':leave',
      animate(600, style({opacity: 0})))
  ])
]
```

This is my HTML element:

```
<span *ngIf="wordCarousel" id="word-carousel"
      #wordCarousel [@fadeAnimation]="'in'">{{wordCarousel[0]}}</span>
```

This is where I change the words:

```
@ViewChild('wordCarousel', {static: false}) wordCarouselEl: ElementRef;

wordCarousel = [
  'Hallo',
  'Hello',
  'Servus'
];
wordCounter = 1;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (this.wordCarousel) {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.wordCarouselEl.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.wordCarousel[this.wordCounter];
      this.wordCounter++;
      if (this.wordCounter >= this.wordCarousel.length) {
        this.wordCounter = 0;
      }
    }, 3000);
  }
```

You can find a working example here: https://angular-ivy-gsunum.stackblitz.io

Thanks for helping me find the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64848450/angular-crossfade-between-images/64849976?

Comment: @Eliseo thats a complete different problem. As you can see I've one div where I'm replacing the content. I know that when I have multiple divs it would be no problem using this answer you pointed me.

Comment: If you see my answer in the SO suggested and the stackblitz you has two animations, one use two divs and another one only one, check my answer and ask if you don't understand something (for me, Angular Animations it's a "hard concept" of Angular)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jo, I prefer use `(animation.done)`to control when the animation finished. So I can not use `:enter` and `:leave`. If you see my answer in the SO suggested and the stackblitz you has two animations, one use two divs and another one only one.

Imagine some like:

```
animations: [
    trigger("fadeAnimation", [
      transition("false=>true", [
        style({ opacity: 0 }), //At begin animation, opacity=0
        animate("2500ms", style({ opacity: 1 }))  //the animation makes opacity=0 to opacity=1
      ]),
      //the animate("2500ms 2000ms" means that the animation spend 2500ms, 
      //but start after 2000ms. So opacity=1 2000ms, then goes to 0 in 2500ms
      transition("true=>false", [
        //here don't use a "initial style", simply makes opacity goes to 0
        animate("2500ms 2000ms", style({ opacity: 0 }))])
    ])
  ]
```

See how the values is false and true and it's not necesary defined a state 'in'

Your .html like:

```html
    <span  id="word-carousel"
          [@fadeAnimation]="toogle" (@fadeAnimation.done)="nextWord($event)">
         {{wordCarousel[wordCounter]}}
    </span>
```

See that `[fadeAnimation]`is equal a "variable", if we change the variable from true to false and from false to true the animations begans, so

```
  toogle:boolean=true;  //declare the variable "toogle"

  ngAfterViewInit() { //in ngAfterViewInits "begins" the animation
                      //see that we use a setTimeout, we want that Angular
                      //"paint" the elements and, after, change the variable
    setTimeout(()=>{
       this.toogle=false;
    })
  }
```

Well, the funcion nextWord

```
nextWord(event: any) {
      //we change the toogle
      this.toogle = !this.toogle;

      //if event.fromState (the value of the animation) is true (when pass from true to false)
      if (event.fromState)
        this.wordCounter = (this.wordCounter + 1) % this.wordCarousel.length;
  }
```

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-66nnyf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)