# My angular image wont swap with angular animations

Tags: angular, image, css-animations

im trying to swap images using angular animations based off a 10 sec timer, but the swap never happens, ive been tinkering with it but i dont know whats wrong, the images are supposed to change when the timer hits 5 but its not working, heres some code snippets of what i tried:

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-levelone',
  templateUrl: './levelone.component.html',
  styleUrl: './levelone.component.css',
  animations: [
    trigger('fade', [
      state('in', style({ 'opacity': '1' })),
      state('out', style({ 'opacity': '0' })),
      transition('in <=> out', [
        animate(1000)
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

```
  startTimer() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      if(this.timeLeft > 0) {
        this.timeLeft--;
        if (this.timeLeft<=5){
          this.state = this.state === 'in' ? 'out' : 'in';
        }
      } else {
        this.timeLeft = 10;
      }
    },1000)
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<img  [@fade]="state" [src]="timeLeft>5 ? '../assets/imag/img1.png' : '../assets/imag/img2.png'" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your variables "state" and "timeLeft" (in .html you write: `<pre>{{timeLeft}} {{state}}</pre>`) you can check what happens.

When we work with animations we need think about the process. I imagine you want in a "tick":

1. fade out the image
2. change the image
3. fade in the image

Well, when we want to manange animations, allow Angular control when the animation it's done. So re-thinking

```
<img [@fade]="state" (@fade.done)="outDone($event)" [src]="img" />
```

where

```
  startTimer() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.timeLeft > 0) {
        this.timeLeft--;
      } else {
        this.timeLeft = 9;
      }
      //see that simply when 5, change the state
      if (this.timeLeft == 5) { 
        this.state = 'out';
      }
    }, 1000);
  }


  outDone(event: any) {
     //in event.fromState we get 'in'--'out'--'in'---'out'....
    if (event.fromState == 'in') {

        //we change the image
        this.img =
          this.img == '../assets/imag/img1.png'
            ? '../assets/imag/img2.png'
            : '../assets/imag/img1.png';

        //and we change the "state"
        this.state = 'in';
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-g2habp?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html)

NOTE: Really I don't like so much the use of setInterval, better aproach is use rxjs operator timer, and subscribe unsubscribe

```
  startTimer() {
    this.subscription=timer(5000,5000).subscribe(_=>this.state='out')
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
```

BTW: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64848450/angular-crossfade-between-images) you have another aproach